# Db2 JSON_VALUE ERROR ON EMPTY is not working as expected

Tags: sql, json, db2

I'm trying to get Db2's [`JSON_VALUE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070417.html?pos=2) `ERROR ON EMPTY` clause to work:

```sql
select json_value(json_object(key 'a' value 1), '$.b' error on empty)
from SYSIBM.DUAL
```

The above doesn't seem to behave as expected. I'm getting a null result:

```
1|
-|
 |
```

In Oracle, this works as expected:

```sql
select json_value(json_object(key 'a' value 1), '$.b' error on empty)
from DUAL
```

... producing

> ORA-40462: JSON_VALUE evaluated to no value

What am I missing? I'm using Db2 LUW (DB2 v11.5.0.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Db2 defaults to `NULL ON ERROR` instead of `ERROR ON ERROR` like Oracle. This produces the expected error:

```sql
select json_value(json_object(key 'a' value 1), '$.b' error on empty error on error)
from SYSIBM.DUAL
```

Yielding

> Result contains no SQL/JSON item.. SQLCODE=-16405, SQLSTATE=22035, DRIVER=4.7.85

According to the SQL:2016 standard, Db2 is compliant, and Oracle is not. From ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E) 6.27 <JSON value function>

```
4) If <JSON value empty behavior> is not specified, then NULL ON EMPTY is implicit.
5) If <JSON value error behavior> is not specified, then NULL ON ERROR is implicit.
```